# Firebase: I need to add a new child to my root, with a specific key (not auto generated)

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I believe it's a really simple task, but I am having trouble adding a new 'child' to my Root in the database seen below:

[image]

(This was not developed by me, I am new to the project).

All I want is to have an additional subchild with the key: 'profiles' added to my Root. I have tried this:

```
firebase.database().ref().child("profiles").push();
```

It didn't work. Documentation has all kinds of advanced examples but I couldn't find something to solve this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That line of code doesn't actually add anything to the database.  All it's doing is generating a new reference to a child called "profiles", which doesn't exist yet.  You need to actually provide some data to add at the new location.  If you just want to write something to "profiles":

```
firebase.database().ref().child("profiles").set("the data to write");
```

If you're just trying to add an empty child, that's not possible.  Empty children simply do not exist in Realtime Database.  They do not work like folders in a filesystem.

Comment: Thank you - I didn't know one can't add an 'empty folder' as you called it.